# IAM Role Doesn't trust Comprehend Medical service principal

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-comprehend

I am trying to create an EntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest in C# and I can't find a DataAccessRoleARN that works.

The code I am using right now is:

```
StartEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest request = new StartEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest()
                {
                    InputDataConfig = input,
                    JobName = "firstjobincsharp",
                    LanguageCode = "en",
                    OutputDataConfig = output,
                    DataAccessRoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::556071315067:role/PassRole"
                };
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Failed to create job due to the provided IAM role doesn't trust Comprehend Medical service principal. Role Arn: arn:aws:iam::556071315067:role/PassRole
```

Comment: What kind of trust relationship does `PassRole` have?

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/access-control-managing-permissions-med.html => *Role-based Permissions required for batch operations*

Comment: this is the trust relationship: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "comprehend.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Should probably be `"comprehendmedical.amazonaws.com"` instead.

Comment: UPDATE: I changed comprehend.amazonaws.com to comprehendmedical.amazonaws.com and now I get this error: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 91A230D30DFFBEA7; S3 Extended Request ID: aX5uHCQkgGObVsNthPABHx7T2pMYBLWw282wLFfE6mPaUbItkkreGILGcL4TT0BG4zn4WNYAy1w=; Proxy: null)

Comment: Probably PassRole does not have the permissions it needs to have, e.g. S3 access, as listed in the link.

Comment: I tried to add access to S3 using this service : "s3.amazonaws.com" but I get the same error (403 access denied)

Comment: You need to fundamentally understand how IAM works, the linked page lists a lot of permissions that are needed. If you do not understand how to connect them, how they interact, etc. I cannot help you, AWS IAM *is* complex, and there is no way around understanding it.